# How can I store user data in Google spreadsheet add-on via Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to develop an add-on using Google apps script. I am wondering can I store some data for the add-on using Google apps script. I am trying to store a username. I am aware of the User Property Service supplied by Google, but it seems that it's only for one user of a script(not add on). I am looking for something like the Registry Key in Windows. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user property service IS for add-ons, in fact it was revamped recently to support other add-on use cases like per-document. I just saw the docs and see your confusion might come from the docs mentioning add-ons only for the document case, but remember an add-on is also a script.